# Java Webapp Printing To A Windows Print Server

Tags: java, cups

I have a Java web application running in JBoss (Linux OS) that I need to print to a printer on a Windows Print Server (let's say called "Building1Room15").

I do not have the option to use CUPS and connect to port 631. All printing must be to a printer controlled by that Windows Server.

How do I "look up" a network printer by name, then obtain a javax.print.PrintService for it so I can print my document?

Even a pointer saying "go look here" would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't make this too complicated - the Linux machine needs to have the printer setup.  Then your O/S controls the printer.  Your life will be easier if there is a default printer so that your code doesn't have to select which printer.

Comment: Believe me, I don't like complicated either. However, my admins insist that the printer be configured via a Windows Print Server. Therefore, I have to print from the Linux environment to the Windows one.

Or did I misinterpret what you were saying?

Comment: In other words, forget about Java for a minute.  If you were running a browser on the Linux environment and you wanted to print then the Windows printer would need to be setup on the Linux side.  Now, how to do that may be a bit of a pain if the printer requires authentication / domain credentials - that's a different topic.

Comment: As the other comments said, you need to set up Samba, and then the printer on the Linux host first, then your java app can access it and print.  Quite possibly using "localhost:631" BUT it would then go from there to the Windows server via Samba to the Windows network printer que

Comment: stdunbar: you're right, I was overthinking it. I set it up on a local machine via the printer config, and the code worked fine. If you'd like to type that up as an answer, I'll mark it.